# Android studio managing shared library for two apps

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Currently I have an android app, where I want extend functionality and make a paid version of the app. I'm working in android studio. After reading android docs on managing projects, it seems using libraries is the best way to do this.

I've never used libraries or modules before and it seems simple for the most part, but I'm having trouble finding the best way to do this,

Would it be best to have separate projects for free and paid versions? If this is the case how would I manage the shared library for both projects? It seems when I import a library the changes don't synchronize from the project I imported it from.

Or would it be best to have one project, with 2 libraries? or two app modules and one shared library? if this were the case I assume I would be able to exclude one of the app modules when building?

To sum up, I need the easiest way to manage a shared code base, and be able to use it for two apps.

Comment: Have you considered using flavors?

Comment: it seems like that may be another option, however it does say on the android docs word for word "when managing free and paid versions of an app, libraries are the way to go". more interested in using libraries